# Is it could or can?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> Therefore in this case, it ***could*** be proved that computers do not slow reading speed down in the conditions of academic and daily reading.

Should this be *could* or *can*?

Also, if you find any better ways to improve the sentence please feel free to change or correct it :)

Comment: If this is true say: `It's proven`. Otherwise `could be proved` sounds correct but not very convincing.

Answer (score 2):

Both can be used, but depending on your choice the tone of the piece would change.
Could implies that the item in question is a possibility, whereas can implies that it is definitive. (Personally I would choose can as it seems that you are writing to persuade or to provide bias evidence as opposed to an unbiased view/balanced argument).

As for additional changes, I suggest that you change "proved" to "proven", remove redundancies such as the 'in this case' after 'therefore' and change the ordering slightly.

This is a completely butchered version that demonstrates how word ordering and choice of words can drastically affect the tone of a piece of writing:

"Therefore, it can be proven that the use of computers does not negatively impact reading speed, regardless of whether the context is academic or day to day reading."

Comment: Is that last sentence worded correctly, or is there an extra word floating around?

Comment: Sorry, that happens sometimes when editing as opposed to constructing. :P

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, in this case, it could be proven that computers do not slow reading speed down in the conditions of academic and daily reading.

OR

> Therefore, in this case, it can be proven that computers do not slow reading speed down in the conditions of academic and daily reading.

I think it really just depends on whether you are trying to say that at some point in the past it *could* be proven, or whether it still *can* be proven, but I *think* you want "can" if you are trying to prove a still-valid point.

Comment: Don't think we didn't notice your substitution of proven for proved.

Comment: @Sam xD, lol. Is that bad? I figured that was what he was after, but I guess, if not, sry, didn't mean to change something he didn't want changed. Let me know, if I need to change it back or something.

Comment: @Sam Honestly, though, doesn't my answer still work either way?